# inline margin works but css doesn't?

Tags: css, html-lists, margin

I'm making an unordered list with no stylings:

```
 <ul style="margin-left:0; list-style-type:none">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do it with css so the code is

```
 <ul class="nothing">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
```

with css:

```
 ul.nothing{list-style-type:none; margin-left:0}
```

So the inline styles works with no bullet and no margin. The css also has no bullet but still has the indent ... why and how do I fix? I can't see a syntax error anywhere.

Comment: try `ul.nothing{list-style-type:none !important; margin-left:0 !important}` You probably have another CSS rule overridding this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add   `padding: 0;` to `ul.nothing` will work.

```
ul.nothing
{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin-left:0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

It will remove default occupied padding.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0ug07du/2/)**

And use following to remove default padding and margin of browser. Then there is no need to write `padding:0` in `ul.nothing`

```
*{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
 }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0ug07du/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

it is working.this is the code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>

<style type="text/css">

   body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
   } 
   ul.nothing {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding:0;
   }

   

</style>
</head>

 <body>
  <ul class="nothing">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
  </ul>
 </body>

</html>
```

**In here we use internal css,but if you use external css style sheet, be careful with your path**